# unexpected result of concatenating column values into single string

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, coalesce

I saw a lot of examples using COALESCE and others "methods" for this purpose .Here is one of them:

```
     @result nvarchar(1024)
     SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + column_name
     FROM some_table
```

expected: [value,value,value]

result:[value     , value     , value]

Has anybody this problem or I must find my mistake in something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have whitespace in the `column_name` values. You should use [`LTRIM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) and [`RTRIM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) around the `column_name` to remove any whitespace.:

```
declare @result nvarchar(1024)

SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + ltrim(rtrim(col1))
FROM yourtable

select @result
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62e96/1)

Or you can use [`REPLACE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) on the final result to remove whitespaces:

```
declare @result nvarchar(1024)

SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + col1
FROM yourtable

select replace(@result, ' ', '')
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62e96/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
@result nvarchar(1024)
SELECT @result = COALESCE(ltrim(rtrim(@result)) + ',', '') + ltrim(rtrim(column_name))
FROM some_table
```